# Windows Azure Mobile Services Queries

Tags: windows, azure-mobile-services

items = await  todoTable.Where(todoItem => todoItem.Text == "abcd").ToCollectionAsync();
i'm trying to make a login page where i compare the user id with the back end but to do so i want the result to be in string format and also i want to know what query to use
it should be like select * from table where userid="user input"

Comment: why don't you set up your query like the sample you have at the beginning?

Comment: it's just a sample ,actually i want to know how this sample works and to create more

Comment: please help me understand this part Where(todoItem => todoItem.Text == "abcd").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table.Where(todoItem => todoItem.Text == "abcd") creates a query on the node.js backend as following:
"select * from todoItem where todoItem.Text = abcd."

*todoItem => todoItem.Text =="abcd"* is called a lambda expression and means all todoItems (normally in a List, in this case it's translated to a query) with a given condition, in this case all items where item.text = abcd